# how to get socket.io client

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, ejs

i wanted to build socket.io server and when setting up the client i have an error (on the client side)
`Failed to load resource:http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OK-egu3 the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

code:
server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http, {cors: {origin: "*"}});
const path = require('path');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.json({extended: true, limit: '1mb'}));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
 console.log("new connection " + socket);
});

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
 res.render('index'/*, { ioS : io }*/);
});

console.log("Ready");

app.listen(3000);
```

index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>socket Respons</h1>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-/KNQL8Nu5gCHLqwqfQjA689Hhoqgi2S84SNUxC3roTe4EhJ9AfLkp8QiQcU8AMzI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    //const io = ;
    const socket = io();
    console.log(socket);
</script>
</html>
```

i have installed the following liblaries:

socket.io
socket.io-client
express
ejs

Answer (score 1):

You're not initializing the client correctly.  Your server is at localhost:3000, but the client doesn't know that, because you haven't told it where to look.

Looking at the [socketio documentation](https://socket.io/get-started/private-messaging-part-1/#client-initialization), you need to pass the URL of the server's socket endpoint:

```
const URL = "http://localhost:3000";
const socket = io(URL, { autoConnect: false });
```

It's worth mentioning that the error message indicates this: "not found."  It's not a verbose error message, but it's a valuable debugging signal.

Comment: Thak you very much

Comment: @Lotar122 if this answer solved your problem, you should accept it, so it can better help others who might have the same issue!